# Turn error reporting ON xampp

Tags: php, error-handling, xampp, error-reporting

So I have xampp and the thing won't report anything at all... I even forced an error and it didn't do anything...

I used

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
```

according to this document http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

also `error_reporting(E_ALL);` doesn't do anything either...

Comment: edit php.ini in c:\xampp\php\php.ini

Comment: I did.... I have error reporting as E_ALL and display errors as on

Comment: When that didn't work I tried these functions

Comment: Should there be some errors at all?

Comment: It doesn't show my php page... just nothing. No errors or anything

Comment: Hm. Have you checked error_log file?

Comment: yea so u have an error in your installation . try a fresh installation

Comment: No errors in php_error_log since yesterday..

Comment: But what about my database? Wont that be lost?

Comment: Have you tried `echo`ing anything to see if you formed your bad code incorrectly?

Comment: Crap, just had that a few weeks ago. I'll but my thinking hat on. Maybe it'll come back ;)

Comment: Hey look at that, made a more insane error making code and it works... but why isn't it showing all errors?

Comment: BTW, instead of doing a clean install of it I replaced just the php folder...

Comment: Anyone just wanna put the answer as "Try clean install of xampp"... as simple as that xD

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Hey look at that, made a more insane error making code and it works... but why isn't it showing all errors?

Probably you're not getting any 'simple' errors like:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in .../.../index.php on line 6
#or
Warning: include(whateveryouwantedto.include): failed to open str(...)
```

But you do get things like:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::Crap() in .../.../index.php on line 6
```

According to my thinking hat, this is because if you don't disable logging in your PHP configuration the 'simple' errors will be sent 'nowhere'. In other words: PHP is 'helping' you by not showing any errors because you either defined `log_errors = On` and/or `error_log = 'php_errors.log'` and it's logging all 'real' errors but your's just don't cut it to the 'real' category.

If this doesn't help, the thinking hat says: "It can't f* remember, but I sure as heaven/hell know it is somewhere in the PHP or Apache config."

Sure hope my thinking hat helped you out.

EDIT:
Tackling this problem might be to find and open php.ini, select all, delete/backspace, save (but keep open) (or save a copy somewhere). Then restart Apache. See if there's any difference. If so, the php configuration is somewhere else. Restore the php file and search your computer or server from the root up for another php.ini.

Also I think you should make sure :

```
log_errors = Off
error_log = "./"
display_errors = On
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

Or in PHP :

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('log_errors', '0');
ini_set('error_log', './');
```

Comment: Please describe what your solution was. For future reference. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

In your folder xampp/php create new folder named logs.
Go to control panel appache logs click php_error_log it will now ask if you want to create the file.

Comment: That was a counterintuitively simple solution. Thanks for posting it. Gary. Probably saved me hours of mucking around the .ini! :)

Answer (score 1):

error_reporting function is sometimes turned off on local servers, for example, Xampp does not support it so you have to go to php.ini and change it there. Hope this helps :).