# PHP MySQL query SELECT error not finding existing table values

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

I am trying to make a web app, that searches by ID/Name input, Database A (client) for existing clients, IF the client exists display Database A(information data) and values on Database B (history of purchases from each client); if not it displays a form to add client to database A and after that add new purchase to database B.

So far this is my code:

index.php  -> this is the search form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name = "inicio" action = "inicio.php">
        Mostrar equipamento de:<input type="text" name="user" value="" />
        <input type="submit" value="ir" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

this is the criteria for displaying Database info:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>ola</title>
    </head>
    <body>

       CLIENTES <?php //chama a ação de index.php
        echo htmlentities($_GET["user"])."<br/>";?>

        <?php
        //declarar variaveis
       $servername = "localhost";
       $username = "phpuser";
       $password = "phpuserpw";
       $dbname = "equipamento";
       $tablename = "clientes";
       $user = "user"; 

       //criar ligação
       $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
       //verifica licação
       if (!$conn) {
           die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());  
       }


       //query
       $sql = "SELECT ID, Nome FROM clientes WHERE Nome='" . $user . "'";
       $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);


       if(mysqli_num_rows($result) !== 0) {
           //output data de cada fila
           while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
               echo "ID: " . $row["ID"]. " Nome: " .$row["Nome"]. "<br>";
           }
       }else {
           echo "O cliente não existe";
       }


     ini_set('display_errors', 1);
     ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
     error_reporting(E_ALL); error_reporting(-1);

       mysqli_close($conn);
       ?>

</body>
</html>
```

I believe the error reports to my query, but I am not experienced enough to understand what could be wrong.
Also, I have added error reporting script but it's not displaying any errors.
Where should it display?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: _I have added error reporting script_ Where?

Comment: Your `ini_set` shall be at the beginning of the script.

Comment: Learn about prepared Statements to prevent SQL injection

Comment: Check for Errors after ` mysqli_query()`

Comment: Display errors using `mysqli_error($conn)` if `mysqli_query` returned `False`.

Comment: echo htmlentities($_GET["user"]) is this showing something ?

Comment: $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());

Comment: Database column is "Nome" or name? Also you are exposed to sql injection.

Comment: @cmnardi that is useful for debugging, but not the best way to handle errors in production ;)

Comment: @bezet it is true!to debug too, try to put before the HTML
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','on');

Comment: @cmnardi Tried your suggestion but no errors displaying? Where should they display? On the page, right? thank you

Comment: Yes. Maybe in the source code of the browser? Is hard to help  without an error message. Is your code running in your machine? Are you using Apache? what is you SO? try to find a way to display errors.

Comment: @cmnardi Yes, I'm using XAMPP, Windows 10

Comment: try to enable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737048/turn-error-reporting-on-xampp or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bIKg8uGqETI