# enable errors php.ini - wamp

Tags: php, wamp

I do not understand why I can not see the php debug errors on the screen.

I'm in a local WAMP environment, which contains:

```
 apache 2.2.22

 php 5.3.13

 mysql 5.5
```

I'm going to the **php.ini** of **C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13**  and I'm modifying the line:

```
 error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT
 display_errors = On
 display_startup_errors = On
```

and the same for the php.ini of **C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\bin**

Can someone help me see the reason why I can not visualize the errors?

Additional features:

[image]

Comment: please check your php included files if they have lines error_reporting(0);
ini_set('display_errors', 0); added... Additionally, do you restarted apache after modifying lines in php ini ?

Comment: also go through this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737048/turn-error-reporting-on-xampp

Comment: @DrJManish 
If I restart, add what I found only in